# Unhandled NSException Line number?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, backtrace, nsexception

I am using an exception handler in my AppDelegate.

```
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
```

I can get the backtrace of the exception by using `NSException`'s `callStackSymbols`

It gives the following details.

```
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01cfe02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x011e2e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01cb3b44 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 196
3   LogError                            0x000047c5 -[ViewController crashIt:] + 133
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x011f6705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
```

and much more.

I can get the class name, method name from this. But I can't find the line number, where the exception raised actually. Is there a way to get the line number from the backtrace or somewhere else?

Comment: A similar question was posted some time ago: [Symbolicating iPhone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/737105) on that question should help you.

Comment: No, in that question someone get the crash report from iTunes. But I get the backtrace from NSException. i.e. in the code itself.